# how could I submit a multipart form using slim3 MVC framework?

Tags: java, upload, slim-3

How could I submit a multipart form using slim3 MVC framework for Google app Engine?

Example:

**form.jsp**:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type=file name='filename'/>
    <input type='text' name='title'/>
</form>
```

**controller/action**:

```
request.getParameter("title");
```

not working. It works only if enctype is not multipart.

What can I do?

I have tried to use

```
MultipartRequest req = new MultipartRequest(request, ".");
```

It just crashes.

Comment: Are you using Serlvet 3 or what MVC framework are you using?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Slim3 MVC Framework for Google app Engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **enctype="multipart/form-data"**, you obtain null values when you try to get data using **getParameter**, I don't remember the especific reason, but it works that way, so this is not a problem with your implementation.

One solution, using slim3, is to use **getAttribute** instead of **getParameter**. In this case, if you need to get more than one value associated whit one of your inputs, for example, if you are submitting a form and you have a group of checkboxes, you can add the word **Array** at the end of the name of the checkboxes in your form; this way, when you get the attribute, slim3 converts it automaticcally into an array of Strings.

You can check this information in the [slim3 documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/slim3appengine/slim3-controller/request-response-servletcontext).

I hope this helps,

Farewell.